# Diffraction: What actually happens in the slit

Tags: double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I’m not a physicist but a curious reader, and I’m trying to understand the slit experiment it all makes sense if I accept that the slit itself has no active affect ... can any one explain what actually happens in the slit, given that even if it is only one atom thick it still has a material presence?
Really appreciate any help in understanding this
Thank you
Frances

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it all makes sense if I accept that the slit itself has no active affect"

Comment: You should really go see Veritasium's video ( https://youtu.be/a8FTr2qMutA ). He explains the Uncertainty Principle using slit diffraction. It can give you a fair idea of what is actually going on in the slit. The slit is not actively participating in the experiment and so it is not causing any fringe pattern. It is the wave nature of the photons as they diffract through the slit that is causing the fringes on the screen. In my opinion, You should also watch Eugene Khutoryansky's video on this ( https://youtu.be/iVpXrbZ4bnU ) to get a reasonably good analogy.

Comment: All the slit does is limit the possible wavelengths of the transverse momentum. The rest falls out from math.

Comment: Imagine a pond. Imagine a wall across the middle of the pond, and a narrow opening in the wall. Imagine waves hitting the wall from one side.  If you can find a way to recreate that experiment, or if you can find a video of somebody else's recreation of that experiment, then it may give you a more intuitive understanding of what happens when waves pass through a "slit."

Comment: I doubt that there is a classical description of what is happening at the slit.  This means that you will necessarily have to accept a quantum mechanical explanation, whether or not that explanation seems to "make sense".

Comment: @DavidWhite if the question is about optical diffraction, it's explainable with classical electromagnetics. No QM required.

Comment: @DavidWhite, exactly. Uncertainty principle is also applicable here. QM is a necessity since the slit here is very thin and the photons are emitting electromagnetic waves.

Comment: Some suggestion https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495078/entanglement-observation/496196#496196

Comment: Thank you for giving me some leads, I'll take a look at the suggested material

Comment: @JohnCuster, it is not correct that "All the slit does is limit the possible wavelengths of the transverse momentum."  In fact, the slit limits the range of possible transverse *positions*, leaving the range of transverse momentum very wide (due to the uncertainty principle in QM).  A classical explanation is easy, using Fermat's principle.

Comment: @S.McGrew - if you limit the transverse positions, you limit the transverse momenta. One is just a Fourier transform of the other. This has nothing in particular to do with the uncertainty principle, and is easily observed in macroscopic wave mechanics in large bodies of water where QM has no applicability. It is just applying the appropriate wave equation.

Comment: @ShishirMaharana Keep in mind that arguments "explaining the HUP" using specific measurement examples are inherently flawed, since the HUP exists independent of the method of measurement.

Comment: @AaronStevens What are you referring to?

Comment: @ShishirMaharana Your first comment

Comment: @AaronStevens Then, how will you explain it mathematically in other ways? Give an example.

Comment: @ShishirMaharana Many QM text books give derivations actually arising from the formalism of QM. I cannot explain all of it in a comment, nor would it be appropriate in a comment.

Comment: @AaronStevens See, this explanation is actually highly controversial. Light as an electromagnetic wave is supposed to be diffracted when the slit size reaches the wavelength of the wave. In Veritasium's video, the presenter accepts this fact at 3:24

Comment: @AaronStevens, Walter Lewin also accepts this explanation. See https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0FGo8mi-5w4

Comment: @JohnCuster, position and momentum are conjugate quantities: squeeze the range of one and the range of the other expands.

Comment: @S.McGrew, I agree.

Comment: Hi everyone and thank you for your contributions ... so is the consensus that the interaction between the physical property of the slit and the partial/wave passing through is not measured or it has no effect?

Comment: Frances Richardson's question of August 18, seems to make sure about the slit not acting just like some polarization filter. contrary to what comments above might suggest. There is diffraction at the slit. I'd like to hear about both - diffraction and sorting out of wavelenght happening ("interaction" in Richardson's comment may be understood as "defraction", I suppose).

Answer (score 5):

The best way to imagine it without getting too deep into mathematics is as Solomon's comment suggests. Imagine a pond with a wall through the middle, and imagine that the wall has a slit in the middle. If there are waves with wavefronts parallel to the wall hitting the wall from one side, some of the wave will get through and form a more circular wave.

[image]

In the slit experiment, of course, light waves are used in stead of water waves, so the behaviour will be slightly different. For example the width of the slit will determine which wavelengths of light will be diffracted. Say the slit has width $d$, then light with wavelength $\lambda\approx d$ will be diffracted. This can also be illustrated in a pond:

[image]

If the slit is larger than the wavelength, the waves will behave as in the 'large gap' image above. As the gap becomes larger, the wavefronts to the right of the gap will become closer and closer to being parallel to the wavefronts left of the gap (an thus not being diffracted). So in the case of light, a slit of only one atom thick will show its presence when light with wavelength around the size of an atom ($\sim10^2\text{pm}$) is sent through the slit it will be diffracted.

Comment: Ref. to "...a slit of only one atom thick " - I wonder what exactly is function of the diameter and the thickness. Both not the same.

Answer (score 3):

A photon is a wave in the EM field that has defined electric and magnetic components.
Photons can also be scattered (direction change) by an interaction with electrons in matter and this is the main reason for diffraction.  (Also photons are only created by electrons (mostly in atoms) and are only absorbed by electrons in atoms).

The interaction of photons with matter is governed by Maxwell’s and Fresnel’s equations, which govern the reflection, transmission, and deflection of light rays using the magnetic and electric susceptibility factors of any given material and the EM variables of the light.
Which photons and how strong they interact as they pass through the aperture is also due to probability (Quantum Mechanics) or, when there are many photons, they can be modelled classically (on average).
Any aperture (even a hula-hoop) will effect light passing through it, and you can see wiki about the Airy disk for a circular aperture.

What is interesting about an aperture is not only this “scattering” of light but the fact that “interference” patterns are also formed when the photons are viewed on a screen.  This “interference” can be viewed with older classical theory as photons cancelling each other in the dark areas ( but violation of energy conservation) or can be viewed quantum mechanically (wave function of light) where the dark areas have been shown to be where no photons fall.
In the QM “photon wave function” explanation light must travel a path that is a multiple of its wavelength (Feynman), thus certain paths are not possible (dark areas - no photons) and the bright areas contain all the photons.  This is similar to how light behaves in a laser cavity for example.

Comment: Ref. to "Photons can also be scattered (direction change) by an interaction with electrons in matter and this is the main reason for diffraction." Newtonian exchange of momentum does not happen (what about angular momentum)?

Comment: @PeterBernhard Isn't a solar sail an example of Newtonian momentum?

Comment: I think so too. I was wondering about both happening at the slit. In your opinion, "Thomson effect" is relevant, see Compton effect, Wikipedia.